# Python: Formatting timeseries data for machine learning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, keras

I am working with [NFL play positional tracking data](https://www.kaggle.com/c/nfl-big-data-bowl-2021/overview/description) where there are multiple rows per play. Such I want to organize my data as such:

x_train = [[a1,b1,c1,...],[a2,b2,c2,...],...,[an,bn,cn,...]]
y_train = [y1,y2,...,yn]

Where x_train holds tracking data from a play and y_train holds the outcome of the play.

I saw [examples of using imdb data for sentiment analysis](https://machinelearningmastery.com/sequence-classification-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/) with a Keras LSTM model and wanted to try the same with my tracking data.
But, I am having issues formatting my x_train.

```
for  rows in plays.itertuples():
    #print(getattr(rows, 'gameId'), gameMax)
    play = isolatePlay(week, getattr(rows, 'gameId'), getattr(rows, 'playId'))
    train_x[count] = play
    count+=1
    print("train_x", train_x)

def isolatePlay(data, gameNum, playNum):
mod = data[data['gameId'] == gameNum]
return mod[mod['playId'] == playNum]
```

The code above goes through my play data, gets a play then finds the tracking data for that play (isolatePlay). I want it to then add the play data to my train_x array. All of my previous attempts did not work and resulted in an array [a1,b1,c1,...,a2,b2,c2,...], simply adding the plays together into an array.

I have tried a variety of methods such as using the append method `train_x = np.append(train_x, [play], axis=0)` but to no avail.

How can I properly achieve my goal of formatting this data for Machine learning?

Edit:

Tried this:

```
 first = True
for  rows in plays.itertuples():
    #print(getattr(rows, 'gameId'), gameMax)
    play = isolatePlay(week, getattr(rows, 'gameId'), getattr(rows, 'playId'))
    if (first):
        train_x = play
        first = False
    else:
       train_x = train_x.append([play])
```

but still ended up with just one array with no separation for the different plays.

I also tried:

```
 first = True
for  rows in plays.itertuples():
    #print(getattr(rows, 'gameId'), gameMax)
    play = isolatePlay(week, getattr(rows, 'gameId'), getattr(rows, 'playId'))
    if (first):
        train_x = [play]
        first = False
    else:
       train_x = train_x.append([play])
    print("train_x", train_x)
```

which threw an error trying on `train_x.append([play])`

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Edit 2 (Solution):

Making train_x into a list as suggested by the answer worked using `train_x.append(play)`

```
 first = True
for  rows in plays.itertuples():
    #print(getattr(rows, 'gameId'), gameMax)
    play = isolatePlay(week, getattr(rows, 'gameId'), getattr(rows, 'playId'))
    if (first):
        train_x = [play]
        first = False
    else:
        train_x.append(play)
        #train_x[len(train_x):] = [play] also works
    print("train_x", train_x)
```

Output was a list of data frames of various lengths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked with the Keras LSTM layer in the past, and this seems like a very interesting application of it. I would like to help, but there are many things that go into formatting data for the LSTM layer and before getting it to work properly I would like to clarify the goal of this application.

The positional play data, is that where players are located on the field?

The play outcome data, is this the results of the play i.e. yards gained/lost, passing/running play, etc.?

What are the values you hope to get out of this? (Categorical or numerical)

EDIT/Answer:

Use the .append() method on a list to add to it.

```
train_x = []
for  rows in plays.itertuples():
     play = isolatePlay(week, getattr(rows, 'gameId'), getattr(rows, 'playId'))
     train_x.append([play])
     count=len(train_x)
```

I mentioned in the comments that you might want to research other models/layers for this application, but I hope this helps with your current issue. If not

Comment: I want to start with the numerical prediction (yards gained). Yes, the data is where the players are located plus velocity, acceleration, and direction they're facing. Play outcome data hold what you might expect, yardage gained, pash or run play, if there was a penalty on the play, etc...

Comment: Ok, great! So just a couple of things, and I ask that if there is someone more knowledgeable correct me if I am wrong here. An LSTM is best at time series data, so if you are looking to predict the outcome of single play outcomes (i.e. Not sticking to a single game or 'set' of plays) you might consider a different kind of Neural Network.

Comment: Using your answer the result data frame is still printing out as a typical array with no separation between the plays.  [a1,b1,c1,...,a2,b2,c2,...]

Comment: train_x.append([play])

Comment: Please edit description with the setup to this code

Comment: You needed to define train_x as a list before appending it.